# Regarding steady state solution of $u_{t}= c^2 u_{xx}$ with $u_{x}(0,t) = c_{1}$ and $u(L,t) = c_{1}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Suppose we have the one dimensional diffusion equation $u_{t} = c^2 u_{xx}$ with the boundary condition $u(L,t) = c_{2} $ and $u_{x}(0,t) = c_{1}$. I donot recognize which type of condition is it? badly, it seems to be the Robin condition.

Suppose I proceed by assuming $u(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$ then $XT' = c^2 X'' T$, but I am thinking how to incorporate the conditions given into the PDE or the process which can give us the steady state solution?

**EDIT:**

I am still thinking of the solution, the question is attached as pic.
[image]
The solution $u(x,t)$ is independent of $t$ in the below solution, may be the steady state then also how to answer the 2nd part as it hints the dependence of time there:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $u(x,t) = w(x) + v(x,t)$ where $w(x)$ is the steady-state. Then we have

$$ w''(x) = 0, \quad w'(0) = w(L) = c_1 $$

which gives $w(x) = c_1(x-L) + c_1$

Now you can use separation of variables to find $v(x,t)$, which is homogeneous on the boundary (of "mixed" type).

Comment: perhaps $w(L) = c_{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{t} = c^2 u_{xx}$$
 with conditions $\quad u(L,t) = c_{2}\quad  \text{and}\quad u_{x}(0,t) = c_{1}$

Inspection only gives the solution :
$$u(x,t)=c_1 x-c_1L+c_2$$
Proof :

$u_t=0$ and $u_{xx}=0$ satisfy $u_t=u_{xx}$

$u(L,t)=c_1 L-c_1L+c_2=c_2$ satisfies the condition $u(L,t) = c_{2}$ .

$u_x(t,x)=c_1$ satisfies the condition $u_t(0,t)=c_1$ .

Comment : Since the solution appears too simple and trivial, probably there is something  missing or wrong in the wording of the question.

Comment: If you are interested, then can we continue this discussion in chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49956639#49956639

Comment: Why the $u(x,t)$ has no dependence on $t$? we must e having an expression for $u(x,t)$ which we tend $t \rightarrow \infty$ will give us the steady state solution independent of $t$?

Comment: Probably because the physical modeling is not complete and the wording of the question not correctly representing the physical behaviour on a correct mathematical form. I alredy answered about this in my comment : "Since the solution appears too simple and trivial, probably there is something missing or wrong in the wording of the question."

Comment: Why don't you fully specify the initial condition on a mathematical form in your question ?